# AWS pinpoint journey - how to transition users from one journey to another?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-php-sdk, aws-pinpoint

With AWS Pinpoint Journeys, I am running a 7step onboarding campaign spaced over 7 days.

While the campaign is running, I notice improvements I can make.

However you cannot edit a journey that is active.

Fine. I duplicate the journey, make the edits and then start the new journey and stop the previous journey. However stopping the previous journey freezes all users in their respective positions in the journey. I have 6000 users onboarding at any given moment. If they are frozen in their respective places, that's many users who don't complete onboarding.

I checked the documentation and there is the [`updateJourneyState`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/api-pinpoint-2016-12-01.html#updatejourneystate) function. It says there is a 'CLOSED' state which i tried calling but it say's it's not supported even on the latest PHP SDK version.

According to the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/pinpoint/latest/userguide/journeys-best-practices.html) closed means:

```
The journey has been developed, reviewed, tested, and published. It has started running and is closed to new participants.

Depending on the journey's schedule and settings, it might have also passed its scheduled end time. Or the journey might have passed its scheduled start time, and it has an entry activity that's set to never add new segment members.

In this phase, you can't add new participants to the journey, and no existing participants can enter the journey for the first time. However, any existing participants who are currently waiting to start an activity can resume the journey.
```

What am I missing? Why can't I simply transition my onboarding users into a new Journey without having to start over and abandon users who started the journey?

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer.
If you have users enter your journey through an event, you can simply change the key of your event.
So in your source code, if you originally have 'user.signup' that triggers the onboarding journey, you can create a new event 'user.signup1' that will trigger a new journey.
With this solution, no new users will enter 'user.signup' because you've removed it from your source code, and the 'user.signup' journey will just continue to run with no new users joining it.